# Passing function with custom data attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible passing a function with a custom data attribute?

This does not work:

```
<div data-myattr="hello();">
</div>
```

```
function hello(){
    console.log('hello');
}
```

When I get the attribute it's a string with the value "hello();" instead of the function. How to solve this?

Comment: Which technology are you using? PHP/jquery? Or is it a javascript only question?

Comment: how you want use that attribute?

Comment: no, this way sure will not work. but according to your purpose you can use whatever you like. e.g. onblur, onclick, etc... what do you need exactly

Comment: I'm using Javascript. Creating my own components using Mozilla x-tag, which is Javacript.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
<div data-myattr="hello"></div>
```

```
function hello(){
    console.log('hello');
}

function executeFunctionFromData(){
    var d = 'hello' // Save `data-myattr` to d; (Obviously, this is just a hardcoded value as an example)
    window[d](); // Execute the function.
}
```

This works because the function `hello` is defined in the global scope, and as such, is a property of the `window` object.

Comment: Good solution - alternatives such as using "eval" give me the chills.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div id='some' data-my-function="function(x){console.log(x);}"></div>
```

js:

```
var myfunction = $('#some').data('my-function');

if(myfunction != undefined){     
    eval("myfunction = "+myfunction, myfunction);    
}

if(typeof myfunction ==="function") {
    myfunction('Cristo Rabani!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Webpack.

```
<div data-func="funcName"></div>
```

```
window.funcName = function() {};
```

Answer (score -2):

Use eval:

```
eval("alert('hello');");
```

Will show hello;

Comment: That is silly. If eval works, callling the function by hello(); works too.

Comment: Silly? Could you explain why?