# Calling and Passing Javascript parameters as part of a HTML5 data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

Based on a solution by Cerbrus here;

[Passing function with custom data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141860/passing-function-with-custom-data-attribute)

Is it possible to pass parameters as part of the custom attribute? So something like;

```
<div data-myattr="hello(foo)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why?

I mean, yes, if you want to do a RegEx match for contents inside the parens, separated by commas, and then inject them.  But that's madness.

Why not just make a second data-attribute?

```
<div data-command="myFunction" data-params="one,two,three"></div>
```

And then grab everything like:

```
var command = document.querySelector("[data-command]"),
    vars = command.dataset.params.split(","),
    funcName = command.dataset.command;


window[funcName](vars[0], vars[1], vars[2]);
```

Or alternatively:

```
window[funcName].apply(undefined, vars);
```